# Why Python's str.format is slower than string concat

Tags: python

Not the perfect benchmark but

```
$python --version
Python 3.4.2
$ python -m timeit 'print("foo" + str(3.14) + "bar")'
100000 loops, best of 3: 16.4 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit 'print("foo{}bar".format(3.14))'
100000 loops, best of 3: 19.2 usec per loop
```

Comment: `format()` is a lot more powerful than simple string concatenation, so I don't think this (if it's at all a significant difference) is all that surprising.

Comment: You should remove the `print` calls, there's no reason to time that as well.

Comment: I ran this multiple times on my i7 laptop without the ``print`` command. They are equally fast, both 0.345 usec per loop (+/- 0.004 usec). Including the print command made no difference with 29.7 usec (+/- 0.1 usec) for both. You can update the question with results from multiple tests and without the print command before everyone think that there's a performance difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right, the one using `format` is *slightly* slower.  But who cares?  You wouldn't do this sort of thing in a performance-critical app, right?

If you want a possible explanation of why `format` should be slower, it's because it must parse the format string.  This is rather more involved than simply converting a number to a string and concatenating.  I'm surprised the difference is as small as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the extra work that `.format()` is doing.

The `.format()` is actually not the work of the String class itself it's from the `Formatter` class which is why you're seeing the extra few seconds, it's offloading the work to a specialised class that's doing all of the heavy lifting.